# PytestDeprecationWarning at test setup: the funcargnames attribute was an alias for fixturenames

Tags: python, django, pytest, django-channels

Following tutorial on https://testdriven.io/, I have created a websocket test for testing my websocket connection:

```
# tests/test_websockets.py

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.test import Client
from channels.db import database_sync_to_async
from channels.layers import get_channel_layer
from channels.testing import WebsocketCommunicator
from nose.tools import assert_equal, assert_is_none, assert_is_not_none, assert_true
import pytest

from dc_wb.routing import application
from posts.models import Trip

TEST_CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels.layers.InMemoryChannelLayer',
    },
}


@database_sync_to_async
def create_user(*,username='rider@example.com',password='pAssw0rd!',group='rider'):
    # Create user.
    user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(
        username=username,
        password=password
    )

    # Create user group.
    user_group, _ = Group.objects.get_or_create(name=group)
    user.groups.add(user_group)
    user.save()
    return user


@pytest.mark.asyncio
@pytest.mark.django_db(transaction=True)
class TestWebsockets:
    async def test_authorized_user_can_connect(self, settings):
        # Use in-memory channel layers for testing.
        settings.CHANNEL_LAYERS = TEST_CHANNEL_LAYERS
        print(settings.CHANNEL_LAYERS)

        # Force authentication to get session ID.
        client = Client()
        user = await create_user()
        client.force_login(user=user)

        # Pass session ID in headers to authenticate.
        communicator = WebsocketCommunicator(
            application=application,
            path='/taxi/',
            headers=[(
                b'cookie',
                f'sessionid={client.cookies["sessionid"].value}'.encode('ascii')
            )]
        )
        connected, _ = await communicator.connect()
        assert_true(connected)
        await communicator.disconnect()
```

I have created `pytest.ini`:

```
[pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = dc_wb.settings
python_files = test_websockets.py
```

but whenever I run `pytest`, I just got this error:

```
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                                                                                  

trips/tests/test_websockets.py E                                                                                                                                                                            [100%]

===================================================================================================== ERRORS ======================================================================================================
________________________________________________________________________ ERROR at setup of TestWebsockets.test_authorized_user_can_connect ________________________________________________________________________

request = <SubRequest '_django_db_marker' for <Function test_authorized_user_can_connect>>

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def _django_db_marker(request):
        """Implement the django_db marker, internal to pytest-django.

        This will dynamically request the ``db``, ``transactional_db`` or
        ``django_db_reset_sequences`` fixtures as required by the django_db marker.
        """
        marker = request.node.get_closest_marker("django_db")
        if marker:
            transaction, reset_sequences = validate_django_db(marker)
            if reset_sequences:
                request.getfixturevalue("django_db_reset_sequences")
            elif transaction:
>               request.getfixturevalue("transactional_db")

../env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytest_django/plugin.py:483: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

request = <SubRequest 'transactional_db' for <Function test_authorized_user_can_connect>>, django_db_setup = None, django_db_blocker = <pytest_django.plugin._DatabaseBlocker object at 0x7f743c9e09e8>

    @pytest.fixture(scope="function")
    def transactional_db(request, django_db_setup, django_db_blocker):
        """Require a django test database with transaction support.

        This will re-initialise the django database for each test and is
        thus slower than the normal ``db`` fixture.

        If you want to use the database with transactions you must request
        this resource.

        If multiple database fixtures are requested, they take precedence
        over each other in the following order (the last one wins): ``db``,
        ``transactional_db``, ``django_db_reset_sequences``.
        """
>       if "django_db_reset_sequences" in request.funcargnames:
E       pytest.PytestDeprecationWarning: The `funcargnames` attribute was an alias for `fixturenames`, since pytest 2.3 - use the newer attribute instead.

../env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytest_django/fixtures.py:199: PytestDeprecationWarning
================================================================================================ warnings summary =================================================================================================
/tmp/taxi-app/server/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nose/importer.py:12
  /tmp/taxi-app/server/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nose/importer.py:12: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
    from imp import find_module, load_module, acquire_lock, release_lock

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/warnings.html
======================================================================================= 1 warnings, 1 error in 0.32 seconds =======================================================================================
```

I'm complete new to testing and all; I'm not even sure how it works, I have tried researching a bit but didn't understand the concepts and there is no particular thing which sorts this out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The tutorial suggests to install an outdated version of `pytest-django` (3.4.8 which is incompatible with `pytest==5`). Upgrade the package via

```
$ pip install --upgrade "pytest-django>=3.5"
```

and the error should disappear. The reason is that `pytest-django==3.4.8` uses `request.funcargnames` to get the list of fixture names, which was deprecated in `pytest==5`. The new version uses the `request.fixturenames` attribute, not raising the deprecation error.