# pytest-django can not work because PytestDeprecationWarning: The `funcargnames` attribute was an alias for `fixturenames`,

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-django

I am trying to test using Pytest-django=3.5.1. However, this error occurred:

```
[PytestDeprecationWarning: The `funcargnames` attribute was an alias for `fixturenames`, since pytest 2.3 - use the newer attribute instead.]
```

**Error:**

```
>       if "live_server" not in request.funcargnames:
E       pytest.PytestDeprecationWarning: The `funcargnames` attribute was an alias for `fixturenames`, since pytest 2.3 - use the newer attribute instead.

>/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytest_django/fixtures.py:397: PytestDeprecationWarning
```

I found this question. It seems to be similar to my problem so I tried it.
[PytestDeprecationWarning at test setup: the funcargnames attribute was an alias for fixturenames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56876817/pytestdeprecationwarning-at-test-setup-the-funcargnames-attribute-was-an-alias)

But it did not solve the problem.

Furthermore, I changed "funcargnames" to "fixturenames" but the error has not solved. The same error occurred. In other words, even if it has funcargnames or fixturenames, the same error will occur.

```py
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope="function")
def _live_server_helper(request):
    """Helper to make live_server work, internal to pytest-django.

    This helper will dynamically request the transactional_db fixture
    for a test which uses the live_server fixture.  This allows the
    server and test to access the database without having to mark
    this explicitly which is handy since it is usually required and
    matches the Django behaviour.

    The separate helper is required since live_server can not request
    transactional_db directly since it is session scoped instead of
    function-scoped.

    It will also override settings only for the duration of the test.
    """
    if "live_server" not in request.fixturenames:
        return

    request.getfixturevalue("transactional_db")

    live_server = request.getfixturevalue("live_server")
    live_server._live_server_modified_settings.enable()
    request.addfinalizer(live_server._live_server_modified_settings.disable)
```

Pytest-django is able to execute without any error. Any suggestions to why is this happening?

Comment: _Furthermore, I changed "funcargnames" to "fixturenames"_ - this indicates that you didn't install the latest version of `pytest-django` as the 3.5.1 doesn't use `funcargnames` at all. Can you add the complete error traceback?

Comment: I reinstalled the latest version. But the same error occurred.

Answer (score 1):

I'm your coworker. I had the same error as you.
As you know, it's because the pytest-django version is not up to date.

You upgraded the pytest-django by using this command.
`$ pip install --upgrade "pytest-django>=3.5"`

But you use docker-compose.
You must upgrade the pytest-django in docker container.

The Dockerfile in backend project calls a requirements-dev.txt file.
There is a specifying the module `pytest-django==3.4.8`.

You just change to `pytest-django==3.5.1`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the error thanks to co-worker.

Cause of error:
When I entered a container running with `docker-compose exec backend bash`, the version of pytest-django in the container was not upgraded.

Solution:
Once it is finished with `docker-compose down`. Next, build without using cache with `docker-compose build —no-cache`. Then pytest-django version was upgraded to 3.5.1 and the error was resolved.